# need help formating text in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know how to use the dataformattext field with a boundfield but now i am taking two of my columns and dividing them for a percentage so i want {0:P1} also how can i stop divide by 0 errors

```
<ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("total2")/Eval("acdcalls")%>'
                            Visible='<%# Eval("total2")/Eval("acdcalls") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do the calculation at the time the data is gathered before binding, and have it do the checks there?

Comment: i could do it that way but i really dont want to edit my stored procedures as they are complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a method to do that.

In the method you will check if the code is not dividing by 0 and all the logic you need (like formatting).

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Divide(Eval("total2"), Eval("acdcalls")) %>'
                            Visible='<%# Divide(Eval("total2"), Eval("acdcalls")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: thanks i didnt even know i could do that, how would i ensure it came as a percent